# Multithreading does not execute properly

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to run two functions(tasks) sequentially using multithreading. The problem is when I am implementing it executes one function completely then steps into the another one. What I expected is to step over to another function while loop completes its first run in the given function.

As a side note, I set `time.sleep()` to simulate the receiving and preparation scenario of some order.

```
from collections import deque
import time
from threading import Thread


class Order_queue:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffer = deque()
    
    def place_order(self, basket):
        for item in basket:
            self.buffer.appendleft(item)
            print(f"Ordered: {item}")
            time.sleep(3)

        
    def serve_order(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        while not self.is_empty():
            served = self.buffer.pop()
            time.sleep(2)
            print(f"Served: {served}")


    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self.buffer)==0
    

order_list = ['pizza','samosa','pasta','biryani','burger']
order = Order_queue()


th1 = Thread(target=order.place_order, args=(order_list,))
th2 = Thread(target=order.serve_order)

th1.start()
th2.start()

th1.join()
th2.join()
```

Output:

```
Ordered: pizza
Ordered: samosa
Ordered: pasta
Ordered: biryani
Ordered: burger
Served: pizza
Served: samosa
Served: pasta
Served: biryani
Served: burger
```

Expected:

```
Ordered: pizza
Served: pizza
Ordered: samosa
Served: samosa
....
```

Comment: There are a total of 3s sleep before the first item would be printed in serve_order, but it only takes 2.5s to print all the items in place_order. Thus, they will all print before even the first item has been served.

Comment: You're getting the results you are because of the call to `th1.join()` near the end of the script which, as the first line of the method's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) states, will "Wait until the thread terminates".

Comment: If you're running the two function sequentially, why are you using multithreading?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need threads to run two functions (tasks) sequentially because it can be done in by using [coroutines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) (a form of non-preemptive multitasking), which are relatively simple to create in Python because all it requires is using a [`yield` expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) inside a function or method.

Similarly, you don't need a `deque` or some other buffer for the tasks since there's never more than one being processed (i.e. ordered and served) at a time.

Here's how to implement things using the approach I am suggesting. Note that the two functions involved really don't need to be part of a `class`, but I put them in one anyway to make things a little more like the code in your question.

```
import time


def coroutine(func):
    """ Decorator to make coroutines automatically start when called. """
    def start(*args, **kwargs):
        cr = func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(cr)
        return cr
    return start


class OrderQueue:

    @coroutine
    def serve_orders(self):
        while True:
            served = (yield)
            print(f'Served: {served}')
            time.sleep(2)

    def place_orders(self, basket):
        server = self.serve_orders()  # Initialize coroutine generator method.
        for item in basket:
            print(f'Ordering: {item}')
            server.send(item)
            time.sleep(0.5)
        server.close()  # Causes coroutine generator method to exit.


order_list = ['pizza', 'samosa', 'pasta', 'biryani', 'burger']

order_queue = OrderQueue()
order_queue.place_orders(order_list)

print('-- Fini --')
```

Output:

```
Ordering: pizza
Served: pizza
Ordering: samosa
Served: samosa
Ordering: pasta
Served: pasta
Ordering: biryani
Served: biryani
Ordering: burger
Served: burger
-- Fini --
```

Comment: Just one question about the thread. I used `time.sleep()` and `.join()` method to synchronize the race problem which is common threads as in the threads, operating system or run-time environment controls the situation . In addition, I have fixed the code so that in `place_order` I set the `time.sleep(**3**)` to ensure it does not get fully executed (prints all the placed orders) hence saving time for `serve_order()` to do its job(I will fix the code above, too). But still did not work. Could you explain why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The code in my answer isn't using multiple threads, and everything in it happens sequentially — execution is just synchronously switching back and forth between the two methods (`place_orders()` and `serve_orders()`) because they are coroutines (which is what I meant about them being a form of non-preemptive multitasking). The exact timing doesn't really matter except for affecting how long it takes for all the orders to be processed.

Comment: Yeah, I have already understood the method used by you so called "coroutine" .My question was that you said in the beginning i got the problem due to `.join()`. In the documentation you referred, it also states "join waits until thread terminates ...... .... **or until the optional timeout occurs**". So that is why i set `time.sleep(0.5)` but it was insufficient since `place_order()` took only 2.5 second to get executed but `serve_order()` finished it execution in 3 secs even in the first iteration so I fixed the code ,namely, `time.sleep(3)`. But it still does not work.

Comment: The method you recommend totally works and It is actually good alternative. But I am just curious why in spite of doing all the steps properly in thread approach it fails to do so.

Comment: If you put all your updates (especially the timeout stuff) into the code in your question, I'll take another look at it and see if I can figure it out. I suspect it's because threads really don't execute concurrently in Python, meaning only one runs at time. Switching from one thread to another primarily (but not exclusively) occurs when the one executing does some I/O, sleeps, or waits for a timeout. When the latter occurs the joined thread stops running until it is its turn again — this make doing things by counting on calls to `sleep()` to stay synchronized very "iffy".

Comment: I did not thoroughly get it. You say , sleeps or waits for a timeout causes thread to stop running. If that is the case, why is counting on calls to `sleep()`  not so probable?

Comment: I meant that doing I/O, or sleeping, or waiting for a timeout, are all times that a switch from one thread to another can occur.  Since the length of time all of those might actually take is imprecise (including `sleep()`), they don't provide a solid timing basis (as in being something you should count on). The problems you're having with your code may simply be proof of that…

Answer (score 0):

The code is working correctly, as @m_dubya said there is a total of 3s sleep between the `append` in `place_order` and the `pop` in `serve_order`.

For example if you change the `sleep` in the `place_order` function to 2 seconds the result will be:

```
Ordered: pizza
Ordered: samosa
Served: pizza
Ordered: pasta
Served: samosa
Ordered: biryani
Served: pasta
Ordered: burger
Served: biryani
Served: burger
```